# Mysql server on MAMP won't start

Tags: mysql, mamp

My Mysql server on MAMP won't start. 
This is the error:

> 161224 00:15:00 mysqld_safe Logging to '/Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_error_log.err'.
>   161224 00:15:00 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql56
>   161224 00:15:01 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended

I already tried the following commands:

```
> ps aux | grep mysql
> lsof -i
> sudo killall -9 mysqld
```

But the server is still not working.

Help ?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145182/mamp-mysql-wont-turn-on) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39953913/mamp-mysql-wont-start)?

Comment: `Logging to '/Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_error_log.err'` ← find anything here?

Answer (score 106):

Remove the files `ib_logfileN` (*N* being the number) from the `MAMP/db/mysql56` folder.

Then restart MAMP.

Should Work!!

Edit: If the above step doesn't work completely, please remove the `ibdata<n>` file as well, based on the comments.

Comment: This worked for me, I had two log files to delete. `ib_logfile1` and `ib_logfile2` also, I killed all the sql processes that were running in the background. `ps -ax | grep 'sql'` and then `kill 12345` where `12345` is the id associated with the respective process. also, in my particular case, my folder was just named `MAMP/db/mysql` not `mysql156`

Comment: You have to get rid of the ibdata<n> file too - it wouldn't work unless I deleted that along with the other two noted above

Comment: This got my MySQL server running - now just need to find out how to get Apache one to start now!  I had to remove ibdata<n> too.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks mate!

Comment: Workkkkss! If on a Mac and using MAMP PRO the path to find these little devils is: `/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql56`

Comment: Works! BUT WHY?

Comment: As Devin mentioned, I had to delete the ibdata<n> file too.

Comment: this cause another issue for me, it says "table doesn't exist" but they are visible. :(
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759170/mysql-table-doesnt-exist-but-it-does-or-it-should?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top

Comment: BE VERY CARFEUL with this technique - I followed this advice moving files ``ib_logfile1``, ``ib_logfile2`` and ``ibdata1`` - which didn't help restart mysql server. I got it going again by switching to default PORTS (8888, etc)  and back again to 80 and 3306. When it was going again, I was back to a brand new wordpress install. (!!!) After a few hair-raising moments I restored my old versions of ``ib_logfile1``, ``ib_logfile2`` and ``ibdata1`` - forced reset of PORT numbers again, and phew, my wordpress site was back in all its glory...

Answer (score 12):

I am working on oS-X (Mac), I was wondering around and came to see [this post](https://juanfra.me/2013/01/mysql-not-starting-mamp-fix/) which help me a lot.
Many readers are being able to solve this problem thanks to the amazing here are the step to fix it out--

> This issue generally occur due to explicitly closing of MAMP serves.

1. Quit MAMP.
2. In the finder go to `Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/`
3. Delete the last log file *(look for a file named ib_logfileN – being N the log number **Eg-ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1**)* we can see in below image.

[image]

4. Please back up these before you delete them.
5. Restart MAMP.

**It Worked for me**, hope will work for you too..

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks.

Comment: Worked for me, too

Comment: Did the job for me too!

Answer (score 4):

I killed the process **mysqlid** via **Activity Monitor** on MacOS and restarted MAMP and MySql run successfully.

**Update:** Even this solution works **without restarting MAMP**.

Answer (score 2):

My MAMPs MySQL stopped working after a power failure, this worked for me:

1. Stop servers from terminal

   - cd /Applications/MAMP/bin
   - ./stop.sh
2. Create my.cnf file in /Applications/MAMP/conf with the following:

   `[mysqld]
   innodb_force_recovery = 1`
3. Start MySQL from same terminal window.

   - ./startMysql.sh
4. Stop MySQL once it has recovered (Check the log in /Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_error_log.err).

   - ./stopMysql.sh
5. Remove the lines from my.cnf, save and start the servers as usual from the MAMP app.

Answer (score 2):

MAMP is so touchy. Here's what worked for me:

`cd /Applications/MAMP`

Move or rename: `mv tmp tmp_OLD`.

Recreate the folder and a subfolder:
`mkdir tmp; mkdir tmp/mysql`

Now start mysql from MAMP. I think it's possible the socket lock file (`tmp/mysql/mysql.sock.lock`) gets corrupted and needs to be regenerated.

Comment: After trying everything else, THIS was the trick that did it for me! Thank you so much!

macOS Big Sur 11.0 Beta with MAMP 5.7

Comment: Tested on MAMP PRO v6.6.4 (Build 34007 Intel)
When other idea failed. This was the solution.
i renamed the mysql folder in the temp directory and re-open MAMP PRO

Answer (score 0):

In some cases it may possible that the MySQL is already running on 3306 port. So, you can change the port number with 3307.

P.S: If you are bound to use 3306 in that case I think you can stop existing MySql server and let MAMP to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything but I don't know why I didn't find this solution yet.

1. Quit Mamp
2. Go  To `/Application/Mamp/tmp/mysql`
3. Delete File `mysql.sock.lock`
4. Start Mamp Server and that's all

+1 if this answer is helpful :)